# Facebook login with symfony https

Tags: php, symfony, docker, facebook-login, ngrok

I install the symfony 4 with fos user bundle + oauth bundle.

I used ngrok for the problem with https, and I use the url : https://3b1b4b45.ngrok.io/. I put this url in the facebook app that I'have created.

The problem is that I still have the error : Insecure Login Blocked: You can’t get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

My local app is on docker, and I repeat that I put on setting facebook the url generated by ngrok.

Please help me. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: _“I put this url in the facebook app that I'have created”_ - and are you also _accessing_ your app via the ngrok tunnel?

Comment: Yes, all works just fine

Comment: So at which point exactly do you get this error then? When it redirects to the login dialog? Check what value the `redirect_uri` parameter has in that URL.

Comment: Yes the redirect_uri has a wrong value, is test.loc :(, how to change that ?

Comment: Probably need to specify some sort of base URL in your symphony setup …

Comment: Strange, I don't found where is set this redirect_uri :(

Comment: It is often not explicitly set, but figured out from the environment.

Comment: @04FS still not found how to set this value :(

Comment: @p3tos so how did you setup login to facebook?